# Wpf main view Model with lots of other view model dependencies

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I am developing a wpf app, and my main view model ctor looks like this. Other VMs are injected via ctor injection as you can see. I need to do this because all the viewmodels are needed to populate the main menu.

But this does not seem right to me. Initially as the app is simple I did not feel any problem, but as the application is growing, it seems to me that the number of ctor parameters are growing and this is not right. Seems to me that Single Responsibility Principle is violated

```
public MultiControllerHomeViewModel
(
    MultiControllerViewModel MCvm, 
    VigilantProcessListViewModel VPLvm, 
    MailSettingsViewModel MSvm, 
    DropboxSettingsViewModel DBSvm, 
    PushbulletSettingsViewModel PBSvm, 
    GeneralHelpViewModel GHvm, 
    LoginViewModel Lvm
)
{...}
```

Can someone please suggest me how to deal with this?

Comment: Seems to me like you're doing exactly the 'right' thing as far as single responsibility principle is concerned, if the only responsibility of your MCHVM class is to be an aggregation of many viewmodels.  If however it has other roles to perform then you may wish to split the class into smaller classes that perform one role each, and would no doubt require fewer sub-VMs providing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `MainMenuViewModel` which's only job is to provide data for the main menu. The `MainMenuViewModel` would take all the other viewmodels as constructor parameter but since it does not anything else, it would not violate the Single Responsibility Principle.

Depending on your code, your `MultiControllerHomeViewModel` might have to take the `MainMenuViewModel` as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Making sense. Thanks.